# Delete a spreadsheet cell in Google Drive for Android

Tags: google-drive

Please forgive me if this is considered off topic, but is it possible to delete a cell/row/column in a spreadsheet of Google Drive for Android? If so, how do I do it? I have tried "long-pressing" but there does not appear to be an option to do it.

Also, related to that, is it possible to change the cell formatting (e.g. remove cell highlighting)?

Answer (score 2):

I am using the latest version of Drive. I know there was a big update not long ago and I see this question was asked before the update.

Anyway, just go to the cell/column/row and highlight it. Then tap on it again.

Options will come up for "Clear" if it is just a cell or range. If it is a row or column "Delete" will be one of the options.

I hope this helps.